# When should I use a stack to convert a recursive function into an iterative one?

Tags: recursion, tree, stack, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've been working on implementing a Binary Search Tree using iterative functions instead of recursive ones and noticed that
I didn't need to create a stack for functions like insert()
But had to create one for functions related to traversing and printing out the nodes in the tree.

I want to know if there is a general rule of thumb for when to use a stack for converting recursive functions to iterative ones.

Comment: Do it when the recursion could be too deep and you're risking stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you didn't need a stack for a function like insert is because you are looking for a destination to place a value. Pretty much just doing a search.

I'm not sure you would need a stack to print out the values unless if the order in which they were printed mattered but in that case you are in effect 'sorting' and not just searching. When handling multiple values and ordering them that would entail the use of a stack.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help!